# How do I applied blurred backgrounds using DraggableScrollableSheet when user swipes up?

Tags: flutter, dart

how do I apply backgrounds blur, only when user swipes up the `DraggableScrollableSheet()`, here is my current code...

```
Stack(
  children: [
    DraggableScrollableSheet(
      initialChildSize: 0.25,
      minChildSize: 0.25,
      maxChildSize: 0.55,
      expand: true,
      builder: (context, scrollController) => BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 2, sigmaY: 2),
        child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.green,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              topRight: Radius.circular(30),
            )
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 10, right: 10),
            child: Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: scrollController,
                itemCount: 25,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text('Item $index'),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

[the first image widget in the background still blurred, the second image backgrounds when user swipes up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUgnA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you were super close to the final result.

Just add a listener to your scroll controller in order to vary the blur if the scrollable sheet is open or not.

```
class BlurredBg extends StatefulWidget {
  const BlurredBg({super.key});

  @override
  State<BlurredBg> createState() => _BlurredBgState();
}

class _BlurredBgState extends State<BlurredBg> {
  final DraggableScrollableController _controller =
      DraggableScrollableController();
  final minSize = 0.25;
  final maxSize = 0.55;
  double blur = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        blur = (_controller.size <= 0.25)
            ? 0.0
            : (_controller.size >= 0.55)
                ? 2.0
                : (_controller.size - 0.25) * (2.0 / 0.3);
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        DraggableScrollableSheet(
          controller: _controller,
          initialChildSize: minSize,
          minChildSize: minSize,
          maxChildSize: maxSize,
          expand: true,
          builder: (context, scrollController) => BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: blur, sigmaY: blur),
            child: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                  )),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 10, right: 10),
                child: Container(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    controller: scrollController,
                    itemCount: 25,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text('Item $index'),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```